# Tkinter автоматически изменяет размер окна при его обновлении

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Есть следующий код:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, size):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.width, self.height = size
        self.change_position(0, 0)
        self.resizable(0, 0)

    def change_position(self, x, y):
        self.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.winfo_x() + x}+{self.winfo_y() + y}')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()
    win = Window(master, (16, 128))
    for i in range(100):
        win.change_position(5, 5)
    master.mainloop()
```

При попытке изменения позиции окна библиотека почему-то изменяет и его размер, при этом возможность изменения размера окна была отключена в коде:

> `self.resizable(0, 0)`

Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Просто после `self.geometry(...)` снова позовите `self.resizable(0, 0)`.
Видимо смена геометрии сбрасывает этот атрибут.